# How to convert datetime in Pacific timezone to UTC timestamp?

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, timestamp

I'm having trouble converting a datetime into a timestamp in UTC.

```
TS_FMT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
t = time.strptime('2012-11-20 00:00:00', TS_FMT)
dt = datetime.datetime(t.tm_year, t.tm_mon, t.tm_mday, t.tm_hour, t.tm_min,
                       t.tm_sec, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles'))
```

At this point, dt is in the "correct" state:

```
datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 20, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Los_Angeles' PST-1 day, 16:00:00 STD>)
```

But doing this:

```
>>> time.mktime(dt.timetuple())
1353369600.0
```

Which is 11/19/12 @ 6:00:00pm EST, which means the timestamp was built assuming a UTC timezone, not PST.

What do I do here to get the timestamp to respect the timezone of the datetime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
import calendar 
calendar.timegm(pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles').localize(datetime.strptime('2012-11-20 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')).utctimetuple())
```

returns

```
1353398400
```

Answer (score 0):

[time.mktime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.mktime) is relative to the system local time, and not UTC. You can get the correct value by calculating the epoch as the time difference between two timezone aware datetime objects. From http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html:

> There are two kinds of date and time objects: “naive” and “aware”.
>
> An aware object has sufficient knowledge of applicable algorithmic and political time adjustments, such as time zone and daylight saving time information, to locate itself relative to other aware objects. An aware object is used to represent a specific moment in time that is not open to interpretation [1].
>
> A naive object does not contain enough information to unambiguously locate itself relative to other date/time objects. Whether a naive object represents Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), local time, or time in some other timezone is purely up to the program, just like it’s up to the program whether a particular number represents metres, miles, or mass. Naive objects are easy to understand and to work with, at the cost of ignoring some aspects of reality.

This is exemplified by attempting the following

```
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 20, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Los_Angeles' PST-1 day, 16:00:00 STD>)
>>> dt - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
>>> (dt - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles'))).total_seconds()
1353369600.0
>>> (dt - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('UTC'))).total_seconds()
1353398400.0
```